# How to set gas price for an OPCODE in a private PoA chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, poa, clique

I have set up a private PoA network on my machine. I can set the gas price and gas limit for all transactions.

Is it possible to set gas price required to sign a transaction for each OPCODE? Like I want to have a different gas price for SSTORE or CREATE rather than the default one.

Comment: Every OPCODE in the EVM has its own Gas Cost. Just modify the numbers and thats it. You can't set gas price because you don't control it. You control gas cost only.

Comment: I modified the params in geth and recompiled it. It works. Not sure if it is the right way to do it though

Comment: the gas per opcode is set in core/vm/jump_table.go, the functions that calculate gas are located in gas_table.go